# What do (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup options mean when installing a package from repository using pip?

Tags: python, git, pip

When installing a package using pip, I get the following message:

```
Obtaining some-package from git+git://github.com/some-user/some-package.git@commit-hash#egg=some_package-dev (from -r requirements.txt
 (line 3))
  git clone in /Users/me/Development/some-env/src/some-package exists with
 URL https://github.com/some-user/some-package.git
  The plan is to install the git repository git://github.com/some-user/some-package.git
What to do?  (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup
```

I see that this particular case is probably caused by a change of protocol in URL (new requirement uses `git://`, while the one already installed uses `https://`).

However, I wonder what exactly happens if I choose either of the choices (switch, ignore, wipe, backup). I'm unable to find an explanation in pip documentation.

Comment: `git clone in X/some-package exists with`. He is complaining that you already have that package and doesn't know what you wanted to do(remove the installed one? make a backup of it? Ignore its existence? No idea what switch means however. Probably `pip` would keep both installed but "hide" one of them[like when choosing between versions of the same software]).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to figure out. “Wipe” probably means remove existing, “backup”—same but keep a copy. “Ignore” is less clear, though, and “switch” is very vague. Anyway, it'd be good to know for sure each option's intended meaning.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A patch explaining this option was merged into the PIP documentation, but it was not released until Pip 6.0 (2014-12-22).  (https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/b5e54fc61c06268c131f1fad3bb4471e8c37bb25).  Here is what that patch says:

> ## --exists-action option
>
> This option specifies default behavior when path already exists.
> Possible cases: downloading files or checking out repositories for installation,
> creating archives. If `--exists-action` is not defined, pip will prompt
> when decision is needed.
>
> - (s)witch
>
>   Only relevant to VCS checkout. Attempt to switch the checkout
>   to the appropriate url and/or revision.
> - (i)gnore
>
>   Abort current operation (e.g. don't copy file, don't create archive,
>   don't modify a checkout).
> - (w)ipe
>
>   Delete the file or VCS checkout before trying to create, download, or checkout a new one.
> - (b)ackup
>
>   Rename the file or checkout to `{name}{'.bak' * n}`, where n is some number
>   of `.bak` extensions, such that the file didn't exist at some point.
>   So the most recent backup will be the one with the largest number after `.bak`.

And here is a link to description of that option in the now-updated documentation:  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#exists-action-option.

Comment: The link to the docs has moved: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#exists-action-option

Comment: Thanks @MikeScotty; I've updated the link in the answer.